# jQuery - handle change event of SELECT tag in table cell

Tags: jquery, row, cell, dropdown

[image]

I'm new to jQuery and I have this table with dropdown inside a cell, I have zero knowledge how to grab the event of 'change' for each. 
What I want is during the event of change selected item of each dropdown I need to to update the corresponding next cell base on the selected value of dropdown. I have tried handling event for each controls using ID's but with this kind of dynamic control I don't have an idea.

I have a little knowledge only but not that much.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* Bind Change Event to Select (First) */
$('select.first').on('change', function() {
    /* Set Value to Variable */
    var selectedText = $(this).val();
    
    /* Append Variable as Text to Next <td/> */
    $(this).parents('td').next().text(selectedText);
}).change(); // Run Change on Init

/* Bind Change Event to Select (Second) */
$('select.second').on('change', function() {
    /* Set Value to Variable */
    var selectedText = $(this).val();
    
    /* Append Variable as Text to 2nd <td/> */
    $(this).parents('td').nextAll().eq(1).text(selectedText);
}).change(); // Run Change on Init

/* Bind Change Event to Select (Target Class) */
$('select.targetClass').on('change', function() {
    /* Set Value to Variable */
    var selectedText = $(this).val();
    
    /* Append Variable as Text to <td.targetedClass/> */
    $(this).parents('td').siblings('.targetedClass').text(selectedText);
}).change(); // Run Change on Init
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Select</td>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>Class</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="first">
                    <option>Test 1</option>
                    <option>Test 2</option>
                    <option>Test 3</option>
                    <option>Test 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="targetedClass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="second">
                    <option>Test 1</option>
                    <option>Test 2</option>
                    <option>Test 3</option>
                    <option>Test 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="targetedClass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="first">
                    <option>Test 1</option>
                    <option>Test 2</option>
                    <option>Test 3</option>
                    <option>Test 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="targetedClass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="second">
                    <option>Test 1</option>
                    <option>Test 2</option>
                    <option>Test 3</option>
                    <option>Test 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="targetedClass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="targetClass">
                    <option>Test 1</option>
                    <option>Test 2</option>
                    <option>Test 3</option>
                    <option>Test 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="targetedClass"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi what if i want to update the next next column? thank you.

Comment: @JeromeHolasca You will basically just need to use any `jQuery` selector: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @JeromeHolasca I've added more examples for you.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, can i ask another? how can i get the prev 'td'? i tried this but im not getting the text $(this).parents('td').prev().text;

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
$('#table').on('change',  function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
    var nextfield = row.find('.classnamefornextfield'); 
    $(nextfield).html(selectedVal);
}
```

Comment: This will work, though I would advise not using the `HTML id Attribute` as the attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element, which the value must be unique within the HTML document. I would suggest using a class name.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following.

```
$("#id of your select drop down ").change(function () {
        alert($('#id of your drop down option:selected').val());
   $('#id of your input').val($('#id of your drop down option:selected').val());

    });
```

Comment: You can fetch the value directly from the `<select/>` element without having to target the selected `<option/>`. Targeting the selected `<option/>` is a great way to fetch a `HTML data-* Attribute`. Also, calling the element within it's own callback is redundant. You can achieve the same thing by leveraging `$(this)`.